# How to get textures applied on mobile devices (android 6.0.1)

Tags: android, google-chrome, textures, webgl, 360-panorama

I've got [this](https://ampawd.github.io/360Viewer) webgl application (360 panorama viewer), that wraps an equirectangular image over a sphere, positioning the camera at the center of that sphere to simulate a real world illusion.

It works on desktop browsers (chrome, ff) but does not on android 6.0.1 google chrome (the result is a black screen) and does work on device's built in browser.
However, without applying a texture things work correctly everywhere and I can see a simple primitives (spheres, cubes, pyramids etc).

the part of the code that creates such view:

```
function load360View(r, center, lats, longs, textureImage) {
    let vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer(),
        uvBuffer = gl.createBuffer(),
        indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer(),
        texture = gl.createTexture(),
        vertices = [],
        texCoords = [],
        indices = [];   

        let theta, phi, x, y, z;
        for (let i = 0; i <= lats; i++) {               
            theta = i * Math.PI/lats;
            for (let j = 0; j <= longs; j++) {
                phi = j * 2 * Math.PI/longs;                    
                x = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
                y = Math.cos(theta);
                z = Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);                    
                vertices.push(r * x + center.x);
                vertices.push(r * y + center.y);
                vertices.push(r * z + center.z);
                texCoords.push( (j / longs) );
                texCoords.push( (i / lats) );
            }               
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < lats; i++) {                
            for (let j = 0; j < longs; j++) {
                let first = (i * (longs + 1)) + j;
                let second = first + longs + 1;

                indices.push(first);
                indices.push(second);
                indices.push(first + 1);

                indices.push(second);
                indices.push(second + 1);
                indices.push(first + 1);                    
            }
        }

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);      
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPositionLoc);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPositionLoc, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);                 
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vtexCoordLoc);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(vtexCoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);         
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureImage);


        if (isPowerOf2(textureImage.width) && isPowerOf2(textureImage.height)) {
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        } else {
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        }           

    return {
        vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer,
        indexBuffer: indexBuffer,
        uvBuffer: uvBuffer,
        indices: indices,
        texture : texture
    }
}
```

**Is this a bug of android's chrome browser or its related to the actually application which would mean that something should be changed ?**

**p.s.**

I Also get this error on firefox desktop (not nightly build):

> Error: WebGL: texImage2D: Chosen format/type incured an expensive reformat: 0x1908/0x1401

Comment: how big is the texture? The max size allowed can be queried with `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)`

Comment: @gman the texture is 6000x3000 which is 2.33 MB

Comment: @gman I just did `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` which gave me `16384` is this a width or height of a texture or a sum of both ?

Comment: 6000x3000 is at a minimum 68meg once uploaded to the GPU (since it has to be uncompressed). As for the limit it's the maximum dimension the GPU can address. You can also run out of memory. For example 16384x16384 would be at least 256meg with out mips and at least 340meg with. Try making your texture 3000x1500 or 1500x750 and see if it works. If it does then you've probably found the issue